# Exception constraint in type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, io, filesystems

I have a problem. I am trying to write down a class type for File system management. I started with a simple class:

```
import Control.Exception

class (Monad m) => Commands m where

  --Similar to catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
  fsCatch
    :: Exception e
    => m a
    -> (e -> m a)
    -> m a

  setCurDir
    :: FilePath
    -> m ()

  caughtError
    :: Exception e
    => e
    -> m ()
  cd
    :: FilePath
    -> m ()
  cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) caughtError
```

There is function cd (to move over directories). It tries to change directory with setCurDir (need to implement) and if something goes wrong it invokes caughtError function.

I want to make two instances: for IO and my 'toy' FileSystem data class.

For IO it is going to look something like this:

```
instance Commands IO where
  fsCatch = catch

  setCurDir = setCurrentDirectory

  caughtError ex | isDoesNotExistError ex = putStrLn "No such directory"
                 | etc...
```

IO has its own IOError. And I am going to make MyFSError for my toy FileSystem. But I got this error in my type class:

```
 * Could not deduce (Exception e0) arising from a use of `fsCatch'
      from the context: Commands m
        bound by the class declaration for `Commands'
        at D:\\University\FP\hw3-olegggatttor\hw3\src\Commands.hs:6:20-27
      The type variable `e0' is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Exception ErrorCall -- Defined in `GHC.Exception'
        instance Exception ArithException
          -- Defined in `GHC.Exception.Type'
        instance Exception SomeException -- Defined in `GHC.Exception.Type'
        ...plus 10 others
        ...plus three instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: fsCatch (setCurDir path) catchedError
      In an equation for `cd':
          cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) catchedError
   |
61 |   cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) catchedError
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Where is the problem and how to fix it? It is necessary to use class type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cd` needs an `Exception e` constraint to call `fsCatch` and `caughtError`.  However, there's nothing in the definition of `cd` or in its type signature that would provide such a constraint.  Heck, the type `e` isn't even *mentioned* in the type signature for `cd`.

For this particular type class, it looks like you want the monad `m` to determine the exception type `e`.  If `m ~ IO`, then `e ~ IOError`, and if `m ~ ToyFilesystem`, then `e ~ MyFSError`.  This can be accomplished using either functional dependencies or associated type families.  I think the consensus is probably that the associated type families approach is the more modern, straightforward one and so should be preferred, but I'll show you both.

For a functional dependencies implementation, you reparametrize the type class to include the exception type `e`, and add an annotation `m -> e` that indicates that the type of the monad uniquely determines the type of the exception:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (Monad m, Exception e) => Commands m e | m -> e where
  fsCatch :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
  setCurDir :: FilePath -> m ()
  caughtError :: e -> m ()
  cd :: FilePath -> m ()
  cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) caughtError
```

and the IO instance looks like:

```
instance Commands IO IOError where
  fsCatch = catch
  setCurDir = setCurrentDirectory
  caughtError ex | isDoesNotExistError ex = putStrLn "No such directory"
```

Note that you don't actually need the `Monad m` or `Exception e` constraints in this class at all, so switching the class declaration to:

```
class Commands m e | m -> e where
  ...
```

works fine.  I would argue that this is better practice -- that no `Monad` or `Exception` constraints should appear anywhere in your class declaration -- but that's an answer for another SO question.

For an associated type families implementation, you add a type family declaration to the class that explicitly maps the monad to its exception type:

```
class (Monad m, Exception (E m)) => Commands m where
  type E m  -- exception type for monad m
  fsCatch :: m a -> (E m -> m a) -> m a
  setCurDir :: FilePath -> m ()
  caughtError :: E m -> m ()
  cd :: FilePath -> m ()
  cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) caughtError
```

Again, the constraints aren't needed here, and you could write:

```
class Commands m where
  ...
```

The instances then specify the the type `E m` for the monad `m`:

```
instance Commands IO where
  type E IO = IOError
  fsCatch = catch
  setCurDir = setCurrentDirectory
  caughtError ex | isDoesNotExistError ex = putStrLn "No such directory"
```

The full examples, for functional dependencies:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import Control.Exception
import System.Directory
import System.IO.Error

class Commands m e | m -> e where
  fsCatch :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
  setCurDir :: FilePath -> m ()
  caughtError :: e -> m ()
  cd :: FilePath -> m ()
  cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) caughtError

instance Commands IO IOError where
  fsCatch = catch
  setCurDir = setCurrentDirectory
  caughtError ex | isDoesNotExistError ex = putStrLn "No such directory"
```

and for associated type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Exception
import System.Directory
import System.IO.Error

class Commands m where
  type E m
  fsCatch :: m a -> (E m -> m a) -> m a
  setCurDir :: FilePath -> m ()
  caughtError :: E m -> m ()
  cd :: FilePath -> m ()
  cd path = fsCatch (setCurDir path) caughtError

instance Commands IO where
  type E IO = IOError
  fsCatch = catch
  setCurDir = setCurrentDirectory
  caughtError ex | isDoesNotExistError ex = putStrLn "No such directory"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Functional dependencies look like the perfect solution for my problem! Great answer